# LTSB Windows 10 Store App

Tags: c#, windows, pixelsense

we need to install a windows store app on a windows 10 LTSB.
Is it somehow possible to legally get an appx package of a store app so we can install it or are there some other ways to do it?

Comment: Do you mean sideload the app?

Comment: Maybe, we need to install an app from the store but on a win 10 LTSB

Answer (score 1):

If you go to **Settings > Updates and Security > For Developers** Go to **Use Developer features** and select **Sideload apps**.

Then you will need to install the certificate for the application, This will be bundled with you appx package. Import the certificate to the local machine under the **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** folder.

Finally, sideload your app onto the machine using Powershell and the `Add-AppxPackage` cmdlet.

You will now have the application installed on that Windows 10 Machine.

EDIT:

I notice you are wanting to install an app you havent created, already on the app store, following these steps had some success to get apps running on LTSB version of Wiindows 10.

*As from http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/windows-10-enterprise-ltsb-no-more-built-in-metro/ab8dbbe5-ef56-47c0-98a0-4a9a7d9763b8?auth=1*

1. Grab C:\Program Files\WindowsApps from Install.WIM on a Windows 10
   Enterprise CB ISO
2. Place them as you see them in the WIM on your real system
   Add-AppXPackage -Register 'C:\Program
   Files\WindowsApps*\AppManifest.xml' -DisableDevelopmentMode
3. (Repeat the last step 2 more times to work around dependency hell)
   Do as this article tells you to do:
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2798317